# Request blockchain for transactions

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, blockchain.info

I have installed bitcoin-qt, so I maintain the blockchain locally. I have a list with transaction hashes strings (i.e f5d8ee39a430901c91a5917b9f2dc19d6d1a0e9cea205b009ca73dd04470b9a6) and I want to request information about those trasactions (input/ouput public keys, value etc).

1. I know that I can do it with blockchain.info api, but the problem is that there is a huge amount of transactions, and the avereage time of a single transaction is 0.3 secs. (So for millions of transactions there must be days)
2. I have also tried [bitcointools](https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcointools) but this project is becoming obsolete with recent versions of Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind.

Any suggestions so as to make the whole procedure more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe)  It is an open source project that will parse the entire blockchain and essentially create a databse with all of the transaction information that you are looking for.  it is worth noting that the setup process does take several days with the current size of the blockchain, but it will allow you to locally query any transaction for the information that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you need to do once you have found your information as that can be a big drive in what tool you use as well. However you can use bitcoind api which is packaged with bitcoin-qt to get all infromation about a transaction using this command.

```
gettransaction <txid>
```

It will return to you all the infromation about that transaction, I would use some other tool build on top of it such as a php api or whatever your favorite language is. Here is one that I made to interact with it via PHP https://github.com/michaeljs1990/Bitcoin-PHP-API .

More about the bitcoind API can be found at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list

Comment: gettransaction is a wallet RPC, which report the ledger effects of a transaction you have in your wallet. You can use getrawtransaction, which works on arbitrary blockchain transactions, but you need to put txindex=1 in your bitcoin.conf for it, and reindex once to rebuild the database with transaction index enabled.